# I want my iframe popup to become visible only when an image/link is clicked, not by default

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, iframe

My iframe Bootstrap modal displays on my page by default, not just when clicked. I want it hidden the rest of the time.

```
 <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
         <div class="modal-header">
             <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
         </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <iframe src="https://prism-communications.wistia.com/medias/05w0jf1niv" style="zoom:0.60" width="99.6%" height="250" frameborder="0"></iframe>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out this snippet will do the job

```
<div class="modal hide fade">
    ...
</div>
```

or:

```
style="display: none"
```